# Why can't GenericArrayTypeImpl be cast to java.lang.Class in java 6, when it can in java 7?

Tags: java, web-services, java-7, classcastexception, java-6

My actual problem is a derivation of the title, but the title is the root cause of my issue:

I am developing a java web application at work. The server my application is to be deployed on, only accepts java 6 or lower (WebLogic 10.3.2)

I need to call a web service in my application. My experience in this area is limited. I have been able to make it work, but when I integrated my code into the web application, compiled and tested it, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createArrayInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createArrayInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createElementInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createElementInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.mypackage.MyClient.invokeService(MyClient.java:64)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

I have traced this error back to being a java version issue. It works in 7, but the Exception is thrown on method execution, if I compile in 6, which I have to do for the web app. The line where my exception is thrown, is the one with `NotificationRecieverSoapInterface.class` below:

```
NotifikationRecieverSoap service = null;
    try {
        service = new NotifikationRecieverSoap(new URL("[myURL].svc?wsdl"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NotificationRecieverSoapInterface notificationService = service.getPort(NotificationRecieverSoapInterface.class);   
    notifikationService.createNotificationRequest(logHeader, loginModule, parmV, priority, recipients);
```

The `Service.getPort()`-method seems identical in the two java versions, so I'm at a loss there. the `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.GenericArrayTypeImpl` are also identical in 6 and 7.

The closest thing I found to a similar problem online, was this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/26020-classcastexception-genericarraytypeimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-class. Unfortunately, the solution here was that there is a bug in Spring, which I am not using...

**Does anyone know more specifically what my problem is, and if it can be worked around, using only Java 6?**

I do have a lot more code to show. I have chosen the parts I think is most relevant to the problem. I can provide jax-ws-generated classes for data structure, or sample xml's as well, on request.

Comment: Share the debug information when you set a breakpoint in your IDE.  That will show us better context

Comment: Good plan. I'll get right to it

Comment: @Woot4Moo ... No luck so far. I'm struggeling with sources and javadocs in my maven-setup. I'm not getting any closer to finding debug-data when breakpointing the lines that throws the exceptions in my own code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I used this method to generate the web service classes: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

I realized that I had used a 1.7 JDK when calling the wsimport.exe. This was incompatible with my 1.6 project. After regenerating the classes with the wsimport.exe found in the correct JDK 1.6, the java classes were slightly different, and compatible with my project's setup.